# How can I obtain the standard errors of regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, standard-error

I know that

$\widehat{\beta}_1
= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i-\bar{x} \right) \left( y_i-\bar{y} \right)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\bar{x} \right)^2}
 =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i-\bar{x} \right)y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\bar{x} \right)^2}$

$\widehat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y}-\widehat{\beta}_1\bar{x}$

and I am trying to prove that

$\sqrt{Var\left[\widehat{\beta}_1\right]} = \frac{\displaystyle s_{y|x}}{\displaystyle s_x\sqrt{N-1}}$

$\sqrt{Var\left[\widehat{\beta}_0\right]} = s_{y|x} \sqrt{\frac{1}{N}+\frac{\bar{x}^2}{s_x^2(N-1)}}$

I found some hints [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173468/how-to-get-the-standard-error-of-linear-regression-parameters) but I am still stuck in the derivations.

- Is $Var[\widehat{\beta}_1]
  = \frac{Var[\sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i-\bar{x} \right)y_i]}{Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\bar{x} \right)^2\right]}
  = \frac{Var[\sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i-\bar{x} \right)y_i]}{s_x^2(N-1)}$ ? Because the covariance of denominator and numerator is zero?
- Is $Var[\sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i-\bar{x} \right)y_i]
  = s_{y|x}^2$ ? Why?
- Why $Cov\left[\bar{y}. \widehat{\beta}_1\right]=Cov\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i, \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left( x_i-\bar{x} \right)y_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i-\bar{x} \right)^2}  \right]=0$?

Comment: Sorry that I have no basic knowledge of matrices in statistics.

Comment: Try it now -- it should work this time

Comment: Based on your comment: You might want to ditch the question on standard errors and focus on the Linear Algebra a bit. Even if someone explains your question wonderfully, you will still lack a major asset in terms of Statistics education; check this [thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21346) for some resources. Even some basic knowledge will get you huge mileage compared to no knowledge of matrices in Statistics. (repost.)