# Reference books on matrices

Tags: references, matrix

Can anyone suggest me some good reference books where different properties and characteristics of matrices are explained in details and in lucid language?

Comment: Related popular post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21346/119261.

Comment: Not a book, but I highly recommend you watch 3b1b's youtube series on linear algebra for a deeper intuitive (and geometeric) understanding of working with matrices.