# Recommendations for Linear Algebra Self Study (PhD preparation)

Tags: references, linear-algebra, phd

This is my first post, so I do apologize if I’ve missed something important.

I’m preparing to pursue a PhD in statistics, and I’ve recently realized that my linear algebra knowledge is not “up to par.”

The class that I took only stopped at orthogonal sub spaces, and I know that’s just not sufficient.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a linear algebra textbook that would be sufficient for self study and get me to the level that I need?

I’ve heard some, good things about *Linear Algebra Done Right* and *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*.

Comment: Some popular recommendations in this answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21351/119261.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Statistijed and welcome to Cross Validated! I am sure you will get a lot of different answers on here but my recommendation (given that you have a good grasp of everything in a basic undergrad linear algebra course (so I would say through Axler Ch.3 at least)) is to focus on "Numerical Linear Algebra" and "Matrix Computations". I find this *computational* approach to linear algebra to be more useful, atleast that has been the case for me so far.

So I'd recommend picking up either [Watkins](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470528338) or [Golub and Van Loan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1421407949) and working through whatever seems most interesting. At the very least make sure you get **SVD** in and maybe also **LU factorization**. The least squares problems might also be interesting to you.

This is just my opinion, of course. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Good sources for learning linear algebra for statistics is books about multiple linear regression of multivariate statistics with appendices detailing what they need. Look at [Seber and Lee](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471415405)  or [Mardia, Kent & Bibby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124712525). Or more modern works like those listed at [Looking for modern references in Mathematical Multivariate Statistics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/527176/looking-for-modern-references-in-mathematical-multivariate-statistics).  Then you will also see what kind of linear algebra you need to understand!

A linear algebra introduction geared for statistics is [Linear Algebra and Learning from Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0692196382), which looks rather interesting.  This is an introduction structured around various tasks to do with data!

Answer (score 2):

These spring to mind :

*Matrix algebra useful for statistics.*
Searle, S. R., & Khuri, A. I. (2017).  John Wiley & Sons.

*Linear Algebra and Matrix Analysis for Statistics*
Banerjee, S., & Roy, A. (2014). Crc Press.

*Numerical linear algebra for applications in statistics.*
Gentle, J. E. (2012). Springer Science & Business Media.

Also, this is a classic, although not specific to statistics:
*Introduction to linear algebra (Vol. 3)*
Strang, G.(1993). Wellesley, MA: Wellesley-Cambridge Press.

Answer (score 1):

> Trefethen, Lloyd N., and David Bau III. *Numerical linear algebra*. SIAM, 1997

is comprehensive easy to read. A good portion of the book is available at the author's [website](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/text.html).

Answer (score 1):

Can't recommend specific books, but what you need to get well-versed on is:

- Some introduction to vector spaces.
- Linear applications and its basic properties.
- Diagonalization and Jordan forms of matrices.
- Inner products, norms and Gram's matrices.

If you master these topics, there's not much linear algebra that will put you in trouble